# How much dried herbs to use per portion of tea?

Tags: tea, herbs, driedherbs

When buying herbal teas in dry form (leaves, ginger, etc) how much are we supposed to use for each serving? Does it depend on the herb?

I am not sure if I should use a full tea spoon or just a couple of leaves or some other quantity, especially in cases where the ingredient is very small, such as dried seeds.

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on what you are using; not just the type of dried matter but also how it was dried, how fine the pieces are, how long you intend to steep it, and so on. If you measure by volume (like with teaspoons) then the quantity will be affected by how densely the matter has settled too.

**Usually the seller will give some indication of how much to use but otherwise I would experiment to find what gives you the best flavour (and doesn't waste expensive ingredients).**

For example, [this loose-leaf English Breakfast tea](https://www.whittard.co.uk/tea/tea-type/black-tea/english-breakfast-loose-tea-MSTR314559.html) recommends "using 1tsp/ 2g per cup" and [this peppermint tea from the same company](https://www.whittard.co.uk/tea/organic-peppermint-loose-tea-MSTR352575.html) recommends "using 2 tsp/ 2g per cup".

Comment: Steeping time would be my prime variable. My partner says I make the best tea [I can't stand the stuff myself] which I achieve by simply having more patience than she does when steeping it, before cooling it off with milk/sugar. 4 minute minimum, for just a regular tea bag. [I don't have to measure quantities, of course, but neither does she.]