# How much mg/gr ginger in tea vs how grams in tea infuser

Tags: tea, herbs, measurements, ginger

When creating ginger tea from grated/small parts of ginger it is not clear to me what is the relationship between how much mg/gr are in the tea vs the grams of grated ginger used.
E.g. if using a tea infuser add 1 full teaspoon and leave in the hot water; the tea itself how much grams (or mg) of ginger is it supposed to have?

**Update**
To give some context, I am asking because since I had read about nutmeg's toxicity I always check the dosages of spices and herbs. So for ginger I read that there is a threshold of ~4grams for no side effects so I wanted to understand if having it as a tea and using too much grated ginger steeped in water could cause to exceed that. Other than this I don't need any exact measurement for any reason

Comment: This seems to be a continuation of https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/123111/how-much-dried-herbs-to-use-per-portion-of-tea and by extrapolation, also https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/123221/measuring-powder-vs-non-powdered-e-g-sugar-with-measure-spoon-and-precision-s

Comment: @Tetsujin: that is good point. There is no mention from seller how much to use and also I could have grated something myself

Comment: It all ends up with the same answer. Try it & see how it works out. Next time you'll know whether you want more or less, longer or shorter.

Comment: @Tetsujin: The question is not about taste though. It is about too much in terms of side-effects. I updated the post for clarity

Comment: This site is about cooking, not health issues.

Comment: @Tetsujin: don't we take proper measurements into account when cooking? So is the idea just put at will regardless if it turns out toxic?

Comment: @Tetsujin: My question is about coooking and not health

Comment: May be I am confused about this in recipes etc

Comment: You seem to be completely confusing the issue. The "health" risks you're talking about are for continued excessive usage of ginger extract, not the stuff in a spice jar, a teaspoon of which is about a gramme. If you're getting through a jar a week, you might want to consider some variety in your diet. Conversely, an inch of ginger root weighs about 25g. The studies seem to be talking about 'health food' ginger capsules, high dosage. If ginger was that bad for you, half of Asia would be ill with it right now. They're not.

Comment: @Tetsujin: How do all these relate to the tea? If you put that inch of ginger root that weighs 25g in hot water to make tea, is it like consuming 25g of ginger?

Comment: "Ginger" is not an absolute. It's not an element, so you cannot accurately tell what percentage of 'purest ginger' any of these 'health advice' pages is discussing. 25g fresh seems to come out around 1g 'pure'… whatever 'pure' may be.

Comment: @Tetsujin: May be my question is not clear. All I am interested in is if I should care how much  grams of grated ginger I put in my tea for any other reason except for taste. After reading about nutmeg https://www.webmd.com/vitamins/ai/ingredientmono-788/nutmeg-and-mace I pay attention to such details. But may be I am misunderstanding something

Comment: @Tetsujin: I basically stop putting nutmeg in food after running into that article I shared

Comment: Bit of an over-reaction. You'd be amazed how many things there are that are beneficial in moderation yet not in excess. If you tried to eliminate them all completely you'd probably die of malnutrition… or boredom.

Comment: @Tetsujin: The thing is that the usage mentioned seemed to me so low I thought even moderated usage my e.g. my oats could lead to problems so I stopped it. I might be misunderstanding something about the dosages and usages though

Comment: All of this scaremongering research reporting is about repeated high dosages. You don't eat exactly the same things every day, do you? On many levels, that's not good for anyone.

Answer (score 3):

There usually is no such thing as "how much grams is the tea supposed to have". Tea recipes are not precise, and it doesn't really matter how much ginger you use.

If there is some reason for you to want a very exact measurement in weight, then it is totally impractial to try to calculate it from a volume measurement. You should instead measure your ginger by weight.

The above assumes that you want to know how many grams of raw ginger you used to make the tea. If you want to know the total amount of ginger extract that you are drinking (after straining out the ginger solids from the tea), that is not something you can find out in practice. I don't doubt that there are laboratories equipped to measure it (given that a professional food chemist first defines precisely what should count as "ginger extract") but it is not doable under home conditions.

Comment: To give some context, I am asking because since I had read about nutmeg's toxicity I always check the dosages of spices and herbs. So for ginger I read that there is a threshold of ~4grams for no side effects so I wanted to understand if having it as a tea and using too much grated ginger steeped in water could cause to exceed that. Other than this I don't need any exact measurement for any reason